# How to get a question by its category in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, categories

I have two activities; the CategoryActivity and QuizQuestionActivity. I want it that when the user clicks on a particular category then the questions of that particular category is displayed in the QuizQuestionActivity, I don't know to do it, PLS your help will be highly appreciated.
This is my `code` so far:

`class CategoryModel(var id: Int, var name: String, var image: Int)`

```
class CategoryActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnCategoryItemClickListener {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityCategoryBinding
private lateinit var categoryAdapter: CategoryAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding = ActivityCategoryBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    initialRecyclerView()
    initialData()


}


private fun initialRecyclerView() {
    binding.categoryRecyclerview.apply {
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@CategoryActivity, 2)
        categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(arrayListOf(), this@CategoryActivity)
        adapter = categoryAdapter
    }}

private fun initialData() {
    val categoryList = ArrayList<CategoryModel>()
    categoryList.apply {
        add(CategoryModel(1, "History", R.drawable.history))
        add(CategoryModel(2, "Bible", R.drawable.bible))
        add(CategoryModel(3, "Geography", R.drawable.geography))
        add(CategoryModel(4, "Biology", R.drawable.biology))
        add(CategoryModel(5, "Arts & Culture", R.drawable.culture))
        add(CategoryModel(6, "Movies", R.drawable.movie))
        add(CategoryModel(7, "Economics", R.drawable.economy))
        add(CategoryModel(8, "Nature", R.drawable.nature))
        add(CategoryModel(9, "Music", R.drawable.music))


    }

    categoryAdapter.setData(categoryList)
}

override fun onItemClick(item: CategoryModel, position: Int) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "${item.name} Quiz Selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Intent(this, QuizQuestionActivity::class.java).also { intent ->
        intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_NAME", item.name)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
    getQuestionsByCategory()
}

fun getQuestionsByCategory(categoryId: Int, position: Int) {
    code for getting the questions by their category
}}
```

My QuestionModel

```
class Question(
val id: Int,
val questionText: String,
val optionOne: String,
val optionTwo: String,
val optionThree: String,
val optionFour: String,
val correctAnswer: Int,
val categoryId: Int)
```

My test Questions:

```
object Constants {
fun getQuestions(): ArrayList<Question> {
    val questionList = ArrayList<Question>()

    val que1 = Question(
        1,
        "The Dead Sea Scrolls were found in 11 caves near the ruins of which place?",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        1
    )
    questionList.add(que1)

    val que2 = Question(
        2,
        "nsdkkaffa",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        2
    )
    questionList.add(que2)

    val que3 = Question(
        3,
        "sfesfefsfe ruins of which place?",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        3
    )
    questionList.add(que3)

    val que4 = Question(
        4,
        "The fewwwww in 11 caves near the ruins of which place?",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        4
    )
    questionList.add(que4)

    val que5 = Question(
        5,
        "The www vdfe found in 11 caves near the ruins of which place?",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        5
    )
    questionList.add(que5)

    val que6 = Question(
        6,
        "The Dedvdrgegee found in 11 caves near the ruins of which place?",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        6
    )
    questionList.add(que6)

    val que7 = Question(
        7,
        "The Dearegergergels were found in 11 caves near the ruins of which place?",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        7
    )
    questionList.add(que7)

    val que8 = Question(
        8,
        "The Dead rgergrgeggegfound in 11 caves near the ruins of which place?",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        8
    )
    questionList.add(que8)

    val que9 = Question(
        9,
        "The Dead Seareewwlls were found in 11 caves near the ruins of which place?",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        9
    )
    questionList.add(que9)

    val que10 = Question(
        10,
        "The Deadrrgrgrggs were found in 11 caves near the ruins of which place?",
        "Nahal Kidron",
        "Tel Megiddo",
        "Qumrān",
        "Wadi Qelt",
        3,
        1
    )
    questionList.add(que10)
    return questionList
}}
```

This is my CategorAdapter Code:

```
class CategoryAdapter(
private var categoryList: ArrayList<CategoryModel>,
var clickListener: OnCategoryItemClickListener):RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder>() {


/**
 * Using viewBinding
 */
class CategoryViewHolder(private val categoryBinding: CategoryBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(categoryBinding.root) {

    fun initialize(item: CategoryModel, action: OnCategoryItemClickListener) {
        categoryBinding.categoryName.text = item.name
        categoryBinding.categoryImage.setImageResource(item.image)

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            action.onItemClick(item, adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryViewHolder {
    return CategoryViewHolder(
        CategoryBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.initialize(categoryList[position], clickListener)
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return categoryList.size
}

fun setData(categoryList: ArrayList<CategoryModel>) {
    this.categoryList = categoryList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}}
```

Comment: instead of `intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_NAME", item.name)` pass category id, receive it in the QuestionActivity and find the quesiton via `getQuestions().find { it.categoryId == passedId }`

Comment: pls can you show me a sample code of what you mean. PLS!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass category id instead category name.

```kotlin
override fun onItemClick(item: CategoryModel, position: Int) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "${item.name} Quiz Selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Intent(this, QuizQuestionActivity::class.java).also { intent ->
        intent.putExtra("CATEGORY_ID", item.id)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

In QuizActivity

```kotlin
class QuizQuestionActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val passedId = intent.extras?.getInt("CATEGORY_ID")
    val question = getQuestions().find { it.categoryId == passedId }
}
```